# How do I get aiohttp-swagger to recognize GET query variables?

Tags: python-3.x, swagger, aiohttp, openapi

I'd like to use aiohttp-swagger in my python Project but I can't figure out how it handles GET URL and POST payload variables.  I have this sample code based on the [quick start example here](http://aiohttp-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html).  The only change I made is that I included a query parameter in the GET URL.

```
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp_swagger import *


async def ping(request):
    """
    ---
    description: This end-point allow to test that service is up.
    tags:
    - Health check
    produces:
    - text/plain
    responses:
        "200":
            description: successful operation. Return "pong" text
        "405":
            description: invalid HTTP Method
    """
    return web.Response(text="pong %s" % request.match_info['var']) # change here (1/2)


app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route('GET', "/ping/{var}", ping) # change here (2/2)

setup_swagger(app)

web.run_app(app, host="127.0.0.1")
```

The Swagger/OpenAPI page that gets generated doesn't seem to be aware of the variable.  I expeected that it'd generate a textbox where I can fill in a value for the "var" query variable.  How do I do this with aio-http?  Is it possible?  If not, is there another library that can handle this?

[image: Swagger page missing "var" textbox]

For the record, I have a C# background and I've done this in the past using the [Swashbuckle library](https://go.weblife.io/browser?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.c-sharpcorner.com%2Farticle%2Fswagger-integration-with-webapi-2-in-mvc%2F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `parameters` attr to your annotation.

Working example:

```
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp_swagger import *


async def ping(request):
    """
    ---
    description: This end-point allow to test that service is up.
    tags:
    - Health check
    parameters: 
    - in: query
      name: var
    produces:
    - text/plain
    responses:
        "200":
            description: successful operation. Return "pong" text
        "405":
            description: invalid HTTP Method
    """
    return web.Response(text="pong %s" % request.match_info['var']) # change here (1/2)


app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route('GET', "/ping/{var}", ping) # change here (2/2)

setup_swagger(app)

web.run_app(app, host="127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: I got the URL to work as I'd expect by changing the parameter "in" value from "query" to "path".  With "query", the URL would be  "http://localhost:8888/ping/{var}?var=abc".  With "path" it's "http://localhost:8888/ping/abc".  I wish there was a way for the library to automatically figure out the parameters so that I don't have to manually type them in.  That's what I'm used to with C#/Swagger/Swashbuckle.